# Where is the source code of 'cvextern.dll' of Emgu OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

Where can I find the source code for 'cvextern.dll' of Emgu OpenCV?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the full source, it's there.
Follow the instructions here : http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/GIT
Afterwards, the cvtextern source should be in the root folder named *Emgu.CV.Extern*

Answer (score 0):

I ran [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the file `cvextern.dll` in my EmguCV installation (for me it was in the directory `C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\bin\x64`) and `cvextern.dll` appears to be a packaging of all the OpenCV DLLs and a few other ones:

[image: Screenshot of Dependency Walker on cvextern.dll]

The source code for OpenCV is available here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv